# The presentations of finite complete local rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, local-rings

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring such that there is a surjection $ \pi:\mathbf{Z}_p[[T_1,\cdots,T_n]]\to R$ of rings where $\mathbf{Z}_p[[T_1,\cdots,T_n]]$ is the ring of formal power series over the ring of $p$-adic integers and $n\geq 1$. Suppose also that the minimal number $r$ of generators of the ideal $\ker(\pi)$ satisfies $r\geq n+1$ for any possible $\pi$. **Is it true that the ring $R/pR$ is a finite ring? If not, then could you give a counter example?**

Comment: Can't you just do something stupid like $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X,Y,Z]]/(X^5,X^4Y,X^3Y^2,X^2Y^3,XY^4,Y^5)$?

Comment: On the other hand, I think that if you replace "minimal number of generators of an ideal" by a number known as *analytic spread*, i. e. minimal number of generators among *all* ideals with the same integral closure as a given one — then the answer is probably yes.

Comment: I think a more natural condition would be to require that the radical of the kernel is generated by at least $n+1$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n=3$ and $R$ to be the quotient by $(T_1,T_2)^k$ for $k\geq 3$. Then your $r=k+1\geq 3+1$. But, $R/pR$ is not a finite ring.

Comment: This looks annoyingly similar to my stupid remark above.

Comment: @DaveBenson Your remark is not stupid. I didn't notice it.